# How to keep track of unit of work when async calls are involved?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

The current thread has a thread ID that can be accessed at `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`.  All synchronous calls within the thread obviously share this ID.

But if you call an asynchronous method, the asynchronous call shows a different managed thread ID.

```
    public void ThreadTest()
    {
        var currentThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        var asyncThreadId = GetThreadIdAsync().Result;
        currentThreadId.ShouldEqual(asyncThreadId); // fails
    }

    private async Task<int> GetThreadIdAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

I'd like some way to be able to see that the second method is part of the same unit of work as the first method, if not by the `ManagedThreadId`, then by something similar.  Is there any context that they share?

Comment: @EliArbel There's some global context information that I want to be able to set at a high level without refactoring thousands of methods with extra parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET has an `ExecutionContext` which flows through async calls (in fact it flows when using almost all threading APIs, e.g. thread-pool. APM, timers - except for `Unsafe*` thread-pool methods or when suspended using `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()`).

You can use `CallContext`, `CorrelationManager` or `AsyncLocal<T>` to add data to the `ExecutionContext`.

Note that adding data to the execution context will force the runtime to **clone** the context every time it's flowed, **which can be costly**.

### `CallContext`

The call context is like a dictionary that flows with the execution context.

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("MyData", 1);
await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("MyData"))); // prints 1
```

`CorrelationManager`, which is mostly used for tracing, uses `CallContext` and allows storing two specific values, an `ActivityId` (a `Guid`) and a `LogicalOperationStack`. For example, WCF sets activity IDs automatically when dispatching service methods, and can even flow the IDs across machines.

```
Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid();
await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId));
```

### `AsyncLocal<T>`

This API was introduced in .NET 4.6 and has several advantages over `CallContext`:

- It supports change notifications
- It's typed
- It's not static

Example:

```
static local = new AsyncLocal<int>(); // you can save this local anywhere

var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    local.Value = i;
    await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"{i} = {local.Value}"));
}));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Looking at ILSpy, it looks like all `AsyncLocal` is doing is call `ExecutionContext.GetLocalValue` and `ExecutionContext.SetLocalValue`...

Comment: @OhadSchneider no need to use ILSpy, go to [the official published source code for it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/asynclocal.cs,ef9ce034697240ba).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Old habits :)

Comment: Excuses, excuses :P